# How to create master and slave database connection in Node Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, master-slave

How to make a connection of Master and Slave database mechanism in Node Express. More specifically with MySQL, the master-slave setting with Mysql in node and express.

Comment: Setting up replication is not done in Node/Express. Just find a generic guide instead of an 'express' one

Comment: May you please more specific I am not getting your point

Comment: I've read your question again, and perhaps I'm not sure what your actual question is. What are you trying to do? Connecting with MySQL doesn't change if you use replication or not...

Comment: actually, I want to connect multiple databases in the express and the database should be MYSQL. To handle SaaS application

Comment: In that case.. do you know how to connect to 1 mysql database? Just do that multiple times.

Comment: but It is not behaving like SaaS architecture. ok I check it again

Comment: I don't think we have the same idea of what 'SaaS architecture' means, and I don't think there's a generally understood definition of this. You have to be a *lot* more specific about what problem you are having

Comment: ok, I figure out more specific information. and Thank you man appreciated your effort.

Comment: You might check out waterline orm and mysql adapter where you can separate read/write and then by create the models for the specific purpose.

Comment: The correct terminology is ["source/replica"](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-terminology-updates/).